# unix script to send mail not working/triggering any email from Informatica command task

Tags: email, unix, informatica-powercenter

I have used the below UNIX script in Informatica command task to attach file in a mail and send to a specific email recepients.  But the task keeps running and not triggering any email.

```
(uuencode -a $filestring* $filestring*; cat $MailBody)  \
| mailx -a $filestring* -s "Today's NBS files from Staging System" \
   $(cat $recp_maillist) -b $(cat $bcc_maillist) -c $(cat $cc_maillist) 

- $cc_maillist: contains CC mail list
- $bcc_maillist: contains BCC mail list
- $recp_maillist: Contains TO mail list
```

Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Actually I use the script in Informatica(PowerCenter), there it actually keep running without any actual result. I have to manually abort it.

Comment: start debugging: `bash -x`.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure on the above script part as it depends on many factors. You can use the post session success mail and can attach the file with %a option as an alternative.

Hope this helps.